# Convert a QString for using in SQL queries

Tags: sql, qt

I want to generate SQL queries from user input for inserting some data into a database.

The user may input anything. Is there a way in Qt to convert such user inputs in string-type values fields?

Comment: `QSqlQuery query(QString)` that will create a query from a QString which is what you will have if you have got the string from some lineedit on a ui? does this help?

Comment: @AngryDuck: no, it doesn't work if the string has reserved characters such as quotation marks. Using bindValue was the solution e.g. this works fine: `query.bindValue(":TextData", QString("Test 'single marks' and \"double marks\""));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"The user may input anything."

That doesn't give us much to go by, but I can give you an example of how I would set up a basic insert query.

```
// I assume you already have a QSqlDatabase object called 'db'
QSqlQuery query(db);
QString s = "INSERT INTO table (colA, colB) VALUES (:valA, :valB);"
query.prepare(s);
// You only need to prepare the query once
// To actually insert values into colA & colB, do this:
query.bindValue(":valA", QString("stuff to put in colA"));
query.bindValue(":valB", QString("other stuff for colB"));
query.exec();
query.finish();  // you probably don't even need this
```

The `bindValue` method takes a `QVariant` as its second argument (I used strings in my example, but you could use anything supported by the variant type).  You just have to make sure the type of the values makes sense for the relevant columns in your database.

Also, I'm using the syntax from PostgreSQL for my example.  I think it's standard, but you may need to change the parameter binding (the `:valA` `:valB` stuff) to match what your db engine expects.

Comment: OK, does bindValue make the replacement for reserved (by SQL syntax) characters then? I'll try it.

Comment: You may have issues if there's a single-quote in the input string, since that's the SQL string delimiter.  I haven't tried it.

Comment: +1: Yes, That's it! I've often questioned what is the advantage of bindValue over simply constructing the query string using .arg(). Now I've got it. bindValue replaces the reserved characters properly and assures, the values having proper type in SQL (adding "" for strings e.g.). BTW. Using single quotes with bindValue works great as well.